# Progressbar with multiple colors WPF

Tags: wpf, progress-bar

i'm trying to make my progressbar look like this:

[image]

[image]

But i have this instead:

[image]

This is the code i have (i created a style for the progressbar with the property "fill" of the indicator):

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Indicator"  >
                                <Rectangle.Fill>
                                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,0" StartPoint="1,0">
                                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="0.5"/>
                                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1"/>
                                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                                </Rectangle.Fill>


                            </Rectangle>
```

Comment: You should update the gradient brush when progress value changes, animation or trigger seems to be a solution here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Just set that indicator's width to the same as that of the parent ProgressBar:

```
<Rectangle x:Name="Indicator" Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ProgressBar}}">
```

Simple!

Comment: Sorry, my bad looks like the part that was doing the change of colors, was the "Animation" rather than "indicator" i used your code, but this time with "animation" and it worked perfectly fine. Thanks